# How do I know if this model is overfitting?

Tags: machine-learning, r, decision-trees, overfitting

This is my example R script for a decision tree:

```
library(rpart)
library(rpart.plot)

db_class <- iris

#TRAIN/TEST
#-------
row_train <- sample(nrow(db_class)*0.8)

#DECISION TREE
#-------
db_class_dc_train <- db_class[row_train,]
db_class_dc_test <- db_class[-row_train,]

colnames(db_class_dc_train)
model_dc <- rpart(Species~., db_class_dc_train)

rpart.plot(model_dc, trace = -1)
summary(model_dc)
```

My question is: How do I know if this model is overfitting? Is there a way to "prune" the tree?

Comment: You can check if your model is overfitting by comparing metrics between your training and test dataset. If you find out your model is overfitting and you want to reduce this (i.e. prune the decision tree as you mention) you can try changing the hyperparameters of your model (e.g. the maximum depth or the minimum number of samples in a leaf node).

Comment: @Oxbowerce Ok, and what are the most important comparing metrics to check?

Comment: This completely depends on the type of problem you are working with, but given that you are working on a classification problem you would look at the accuracy.

Comment: @Oxbowerce for example, with the model that I have brought back in the question I obtain an index of accuracy of 0.9667. In relation to what I say that my decision tree goes well or it goes in overfitting? Is there a threshold value for accuracy?

Comment: You compare the accuracy value obtained on both your training and test dataset. If the accuracy is (significantly) higher on your training set you are overfitting since you are fitting your model to noise present in your training dataset.

Comment: how significant is significantly higher? Is there any threshold between training and testing to conclude overfitting?

Comment: @Oxbowerce I was convinced that there was no accuracy index for the train part. Can I calculate it for the example I wrote as well? Isn't it always 100%?

Comment: You can always calculate the accuracy for classification problems, independent on whether this data is in your training or test dataset. This is not always 100%, and if it is 100% it is quite likely that your model is overfitting.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, check the training and test/validation metrics and compare them. If the training metric is much better than the test/validation metric, then there are high chances you are overfitting.

Another way to check for overfitting is to plot learning curves. They are basically curves for model performance. Check out the sklearn page for `learning_curves`.